# Load json array using ng-click with a service

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, angularjs, angular-routing

I am still an angular noob. I have one json file with multiple arrays. 
How can I load a specific array based on the route using ng-click?

**For example, it would be like this. ng-click would load a specific array based on the current route.**

```
    www.sample.com/main/:data1/title1  --- Load menu.data1[x].title1 from json
    www.sample.com/main/:data2/title2  --- Load menu.data2[x].title2 from json
```

I tried creating a service to grab the $routeParams.data, and then search the array to look for the corresponding description, but it returns undefined.

**Here is the service I have been working on.**

```
app.factory('getCurrent', function(){
return {
 getData : function(routeId, myArray) {
     for(var x=0; x<myArray.length; x++){
         console.log('myArray', myArray);  // shows undefined
          if(routeId == [myArray][x].title1){
            return [myArray][x].description;
        }   
     }  
}
```

}
});

**I have a lot of data so, I was thinking about having different controllers for each one. Anyway, here is data from my controller.**

```
$scope.getmyData = function(routeId, myArray){
    getCurrent.getData(routeId, myArray);
```

};

**Here is the template from my route and my link from which I calling this.**

```
when('/main/:data/:title', {
    template: '<h1>{{ getmyData(data, title) }}</h1>',
    controller: 'data1'
  });

<a href  id="{{ $index }}" ng-click="getmyIndex(data, title);">{{ x.title1 }}</a>
```

Comment: Please show getmyIndex

Comment: Here is the getmyIndex function `$scope.getmyIndex = function(routeId, myArray){
  getCurrent.getData(routeId, myArray);
 };`